# "Unable to look up library. Check the ID and access permissions and try again." Firebase Google Apps Script

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script

I am unable to find the Firebase library for Google Apps Script.
I followed the following instruction:

https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase

The in this article mentioned project key / script id can not be found when trying to add the library in my new project.

The Look Up renders:

Unable to look up library. Check the ID and access permissions and try again.

Am I missing something? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try googling `google firebase libraries`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Use the Script ID

<sup>as opposed to the Project Key</sup>

For this library it's:

> 1hguuh4Zx72XVC1Zldm_vTtcUUKUA6iBUOoGnJUWLfqDWx5WlOJHqYkrt

#### New editor vs Legacy

With the move to the new editor, using **Project Keys** no longer work.

See the different instructions for the New vs Legacy Editor in the docs:

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries

#### Adding a library if you only have the Project Key

If you can't find the ID for a particular script, while the Legacy editor is still available you can switch to the Legacy editor to add it with a Project Key, and then switch back to the new editor.

#### Finding the Script ID if you only have the Project Key

Maybe you want to get the ID for later reference. To get this, once you have it added, you can press the "three dots" button next to the library name and select "Open in new tab". Once you have it open, you can get the ID from the URL.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: This was the ID I was looking for. BTW where did you get that ID for FirebaseApp library?

Comment: @bikram in my answer you can see one method of finding it, but in this case it is on the same website under the heading "SOURCE" - https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/source

Answer (score 2):

I came here because I tried to use a deployment id for a script library.

The fix was to use the project id which I found under project settings.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from 'iansedano' is correct. I just want to add that a to get the 'script id' it's easier to just go to the settings and copy it from there:

[image]